# Long email address going out of border in Bootstrap 3 thumbnail

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, thumbnails, umbraco7

when I try to insert a member profile any long email goes out of the bder in bootstrap 2 thumbnail. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY18O.png)

Here is the razor syntax i m using in umbraco

```html
<div class="thumbnail " style="padding:0;">
  <img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(item.GetValue<string>(" memberImage ")).Url" class="left" style="width:100%">

  <div class="caption">
    <h4 class="">@item.GetValue("name")</h4>
    <p>@item.GetValue("title")</p>

    @if (item.GetValue("companyLogo") != null) {
    <a href="@item.GetValue(" companyLink ")" target="_blank">
         <img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(item.GetValue<string>("companyLogo")).Url" class=" " style=" float:left;"> 
        </a> }

    <p class="" style="clear:both">@item.GetValue("bio")</p>

    @*<a href="@item.GetValue(" companyLink ")" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>*@
    <a href="mailto:@item.GetValue(" contactDetails ")">@item.GetValue("contactDetails")</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

What might be the reason for this? I would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for it is that your email address is longer than the width of the containing element, and considering your email address is a single 'word', the browser is unsure where to break it up.

To get around this, the **best** solution in my opinion would be to make use of ellipsis (the three dots at the end of a word that indicate that there's more text than is shown). This can be done by applying the following CSS to the email address:

```
.caption a {
  width: 250px; /* you need a maximum width for the text */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: HI Obsidian css ellipsis worked but the client didnt like the overall design haha. But thanks it did solved the width issue. :)